# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float', but I have no &

Tags: python, if-statement, typeerror

Here is part of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyfits 
from astropy.io import ascii

def create_randoms(min_z,max_z,min_mass):

        Do some calculations and use it to 
        write into a file 


        if (max_z == 1.0 and min_mass == 1e13):
                ascii.write(data_1, '/home/Documents/0.0_zphot_1.0.dat', Writer=ascii.FixedWidthNoHeader, delimiter=None)
```

Exactly in the `if` statement, I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'
```

I call the function by:

```
create_randoms(0.0,1.0,1e13)
```

I don't know why it doesn't seem to like the values `1.0 and 1e13`. I am *not* using the bitwise `&` here, and instead I am correctly using the logical operator `and`. But still it is throwing me with the error.

Full error traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-d5f507b12cc0> in <module>()
----> 1 create_randoms(0.0,1.0,1e13,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1)

/home/ssridhar/Documents/PhD_materials/Python/correlation_func/100_Hband_halos/jackknife_random_creation.py in create_randoms(min_z, max_z, min_mass, r1, r2, r3, r4, d1, d2, d3, d4)
    119         """ WRITING FILES ACCORDINGLY """
    120 
--> 121         if (max_z == '1.0' and min_mass == '1e13'):
    122                 ascii.write(data_1, '/home/ssridhar/Documents/PhD_materials/2pt_correlation_master_2/Input/100_Hband_halos/jackknife/M200>1e13/K1_100sq_M200>1e13_xyz_0.0<zphot0.001<1.0.dat', Writer=ascii.FixedWidthNoHeader, delimiter=None)
    123 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'
```

Comment: In Python `&` is the bitwise operator

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback?

Comment: @logic I have also tried with `&`, it doesnt seem to work. Get back the same error.

Comment: You don't have a `&` in your code; please include the full traceback so we can pinpoint where the error really happens.

Comment: You are working with obsolete bytecode; a *previous revision* had that error but you did not reload the code. Reload the module or restart ipython.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That seems to work!! Could I please have more enlightenment about this?

Comment: @logic: I have made the edit!

Comment: @ThePredator: written up an explanation as an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python compiles your code to bytecode, then runs that. But bytecode doesn't make for a readable error message. When an error occurs, Python loads the original source code from disk to show what lines are causing the error.

So when you *edit your code*, but don't reload the bytecode in Python or restart the Python interpreter, your error messages will by out of sync. Old code with the problem is run, but the traceback shows the new code.

In ipython, reload the code, or to be 100% sure, restart the interpreter.